# How to achieve a realistic display with bright colours?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, export, shaders

I would like to model an iPhone wich shows a display with bright colors. When I am using dark color palette, there is no problem but when I use the light color palette, then it appears too brigh.[image: the model with bright color palette]

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The problem of the original post is that the Image is connected to *both* the Base Color and Emission. This means the surface reaction to the surrounding lights (as a result of Base Color) is in addition to the Emission. The solution here is to either just use an Emission shader (Principled is for too complicated for this situation) or disconnect the Base Color and set it to black (or dark grey).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here is that the output from the Image Texture is connected to both the Base Color and the Emission inputs of the Principled shader node. The Emission will produce the effect of the glowing screen while the Base Color will also produce an image of the glowing screen - in addition to the Emission but based on any incident light. This means you are effectively including your 'screen' image twice - once for emission and again in response to any light hitting the surface - so it appears "too bright".

The solution here is to either just use an Emission shader node in place of the Principled shader (Principled is arguably overkill for this situation) or simply disconnect the Base Color and set it to black (or a suitably dark color) to represent the screen when it is 'off'.